# Is it possible to loop through some numbers in a file and check if they are sorted without the need to read them into a vector then check the vector

Tags: c++, file, sorting

I would like to know if I can perform operations on some numbers straight in the file without

the need to read them. I wrote this code to check if a file is sorted but I had to read them

first into a vector and then check if the vector is sorted or not but then I figured that this

code might be inefficient since I had to make few extra steps. this is the code:

// method to check if the numbers are already sorted:

```
bool number_sorted(vector <int> vector){
    bool is_sorted = true;
     for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < vector.size(); j++){
            if(vector[i] > vector[j]){
                is_sorted = false;  
                cout << vector[i] << " and " << vector[j] << " are in the wrong order" << endl; 
            }
        }
    } 
    return is_sorted;
}
```

// method to sort the numbers:

```
vector <int> sort(vector <int> vector){
    for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < vector.size(); j++){
            if(vector[i] > vector[j]){
                int temp = vector[i]; 
                vector[i] = vector[j]; 
                vector[j] = temp; 
            }
        }
    }

    return vector; 
}
```

// Main methdod:

```
int main(){
    vector <int> list; 
    fstream fs;
   fs.open("/Users/brah79/Downloads/skola/c++/inlämningsuppgiter/number1.txt"); 
    
    bool is_sorted = number_sorted(list); 
    if(is_sorted){
        cout << "the list of numbers is sorted" << endl; 
    }

    else{
        sort(list); 
    }
```

as you can see everything is performed on a vector first but I want to make the check and the

sorting straight on the file. Hope I made myself clear

Comment: "without the need to read them" - no, certainly not.  "without the need to read them into a vector" - yes.

Comment: @ThomasWeller haha my bad I meant without reading them into the vector

Comment: To work out if something is sorted you only need to compare the adjacent pairs of numbers. You are doing _way_ too much work, vector or not.

Comment: "...without the need to read them." No. you cannot check if some numbers are sorted when you do not know the numbers. Though you need no container. It is sufficient to compare adjacent numbers

Comment: Stop for a moment, and try to wrap your brain around the following question: if the contents of the file are sorted, what can you say (with utmost confidence in you being right) about reading each number from a file, and what can be said about it in relationship to the previous number in the file?

Comment: you are thinking too compilcated. I suggest to forget about the code for a moment, but consider you see a sequence of numbers on a screen. What can you do to tell if the sequence is sorted ? Would you need to write down the numbers? Or can you do it wihtout that?

Comment: Clean-up tip: Include `algorithm` and `sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());`.

Comment: You don't need to compare every number to every other number. (I believe you looked at your sorting function and assumed that *checking* the order must look similar.)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I would just compare each number to the previous number and that's exactly what the function number_sorted() is doing. it's checking if a vector is sorted or not. I just need to access the numbers in the file and check the file not the vector

Comment: So is your question literally "How do I read one number from a file?" That'd be `fs >> someVariable`

Comment: @Botje no sir that's not my question, my question is how do I sort a file or check if a file is sorted without the need of transforming the numbers into a vector or array or whatever. I know the algorithm for checking if a vector is sorted because I know how to access the elements of a vector but not a file.

Comment: Read a number. Compare it to the previous number. Read another number. Compare it to the previous number. Repeat until you spot a number that is not higher or you reach the end. As for sorting it, you cannot do that without reading everything into memory, no.

Comment: where do you read the numbers from the file into a vector in your code? Just dont do that. Instead remember the previous number and compare it to the current one. Yes it is a little more complicated to write the code in a "nice" way, to have reading from the file and the logic for `is_sorted` separated and testable, but thats the bonus points, before that, as others stated, you need to go some steps back: Do not read the numbers into a vector, do not put the logic for `is_sorted` into a separate function, the rest is already there in your code

Comment: @Botje tha's what I wanted to know. So my logic was right I have to load all the numbers to memory first then sort them? thanks

Comment: btw not sure if it was mentioned already, but your method to check if the vector is sorted is wrong. I mean it produces correct result but it is so inefficient that one can consider it to be broken. You do not need a nested loop. After all the comments I actually think thats your initial misunderstanding. You only need to check if `x[i] <= x[i+1]` and if thats the case then it does already follow that `x[i] <= x[j]` for any `i < j`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I thought that's how bubble sort work

Comment: @brah79 I dont know how bubble sort works :), but doesnt matter, sorting is much more complicated / complex than checking if a vector is sorted. Its not the same task, and does not require the same algorithm

Answer (score 3):

You have to read file there is not other way.
But you do not have to keep everything in `vector`

```cpp
bool areIntsInStreamSorted(std::istream& in)
{
    return std::is_sorted(std::istream_iterator<int>{in}, {}) && in.eof();
}

bool areIntsInFileSorted(std::filesystem::path p)
{
    std::ifstream in{p};
    return areIntsInStreamSorted(in);
}
```

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator
- [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T5jvPhaPf)

Comment: I always have to think twice to decide if `istream_iterator` is helpful for a beginner, but then my answer is a clear Yes. They will have to read some documentation to understand the code, and they can learn a lot from that

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it seems like I will need to learn them sooner or later so I might have to start now. thanks sir

Comment: While this is a fairly basic question, it's a reasonable question. This answer might be more valuable by explaining a bit more about the role of iterators. `is_sorted` requires an iterator pair. Reading the file into a vector gives you vector iterators, which would work. But this example shows that you can also create an iterator pair directly for the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at your implementation:

> ```
> bool number_sorted(vector <int> vector){
>     bool is_sorted = true;
>      for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
>         for(int j = i + 1; j < vector.size(); j++){
>             if(vector[i] > vector[j]){
>                 is_sorted = false;  
>                 cout << vector[i] << " and " << vector[j] << " are in the wrong order" << endl; 
>             }
>         }
>     } 
>     return is_sorted;
> }
> ```

You consider every element `vector[i]` and then check for all `j > i` that `vector[i]` is not greater than `vector[j]`. If it is, the vector is not sorted. If you you encounter no such pair of elements `vector[i]` and `vector[j]` then the vector is sorted.

If this was the way to check if a sequence of numbers is sorted, then yes, then you need all numbers in memory.

However, it is not. It is much simpler. In a sequence that is not sorted, there is at least one index `i` where

```
 vector[i] > vector[i+1]
```

and thats it. If any pair of adjacent elements is sorted, then the whole sequence is sorted too.

You only ever have to compare one number with the next. You do not need to store all elements to check if they are sorted. When you read from the file, remember the previous number, read the next, and check if the next is bigger or equal the previous one.

Comment: ahaaa now I understand, makes sense actually. thank you sir

Comment: Hi again guys! this is so embarrassing but I have been trying to figure out a way to solve this problem for 2 days but couldn't and I can't find anything online either. I wanna know how to check if a file with a bunch of numbers is sorted or not without actually loading the file into memory. I have 3 huge files and I wanna avoid moving them over to a vector so I wanna do the checking straight in the file. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @brah79 did you actually try Mareks answer? It has all you need.

Comment: I didn't understand it as I still don't know anything about iterators or filesystems. I wanted a simpler approach @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: @brah79 you can learn about iterators. "filesystems" ?!? Do you mean filestreams? You need a filestream to read from a file. YOu cannot check if numbers in a file are sorted without reading the numbers from the file, i though we already got that straight. Do you actually have problems to read numbers from a file? Do that. Then checking if they are sorted should be not that hard

Comment: No not filestreams filesystem it's in Mareks code. I don't even know what that is. I can read all the numbers and I remember you mentioned something about keeping track of the previous number to compare to the current but I don't know how to to that. I can only read the current number in file with a while loop

Comment: @brah79 `std::filesystem::path` is just a path. You can read the documentation if you dont know what it is: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path.

Comment: @brah79 for the previous value thingy, not sure how to help. Frankly, its something really basic. As an exercise you can use a vector, start with `previous = x[0]; current = x[1];` now write a loop and try to figure out a way to update the two in a loop where you only access a single element in one iteration

Comment: thank you I'll try to learn about iterators